# Change variable attribute, evaluate other attributes accordingly

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am trying to find a way for getting all attributes to evaluate after one attribute change within the class, without calling a function outside the class.

```
class Students:
        def __init__(self, name, mylist):
            self.name = name
            self.subjects = mylist
            self.credits =  len(self.subjects) * 2
            
        def credits_calc(self):
            self.credits = len(self.subjects) * 2
            return self.credits

john = Students("John", ["Maths", "English"])
print(john.subjects)
print(john.credits)

john.subjects.append("History")
print(john.subjects) # --> subjects attribute updated.
print(john.credits)  # --> obviously not updated. Still returns initial value.
```

I have to call the function outside the class to to have the other attributes updated

```
john.credits_calc() # I know I can take the returned value.
print(john.credits) # --> updated after calling the function.
```

So my question is how to get the other attributes to evaluate if one attribute is changed without the need to manually call the function later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator. There are additional methods you can add on to this, particularly the *fset* and *fdel* logic of this attribute, the code below simply defines the *fget* behavior.

```
class Students:
    def __init__(self, name, mylist):
        self.name = name
        self.subjects = mylist

    @property
    def credits(self):
        return len(self.subjects) * 2


john = Students("John", ["Maths", "English"])
print(john.credits)  # 4

john.subjects.append("History")
print(john.credits)  # 6
```